# How to convert 16 bit image to 32 bit image in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv

I am novice in OpenCV. My program reads image data in 16 bit unsigned int. I need to multiply the image data by some gain of 16 bit unsigned int. So, the resulting data should be kept in 32 bit image file. 
I tried following, but I get 8 bit all white image. Please help.

```
    Mat inputData = Mat(Size(width, height), CV_16U, inputdata); 
    inputData.convertTo(input1Data, CV_32F);
    input1Data = input1Data * gain;//gain is ushort
```

Comment: how do you display the image? `imshow` assumes float/double values to be between 0 (black) and 1 (white) so maybe just bring your values in that range, e.g. `cv::imshow("test", input1Data/65000.0f)` or divide by another value that fits better to your values ;)

Comment: @Micka, thanks for your answer. Could you please check additional information I added. I would very much appreciate your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Micka noticed in the comment, first of all we need to scale inputData to have values between 0.0f and 1.0f by passing a scaling factor:

```
inputData.convertTo(input1Data, CV_32F, 1.0/65535.0f); // since in inputData 
                                                       // we have values between 0 and 
                                                       // 65535 so all resulted values 
                                                       // will be between 0.0f and 1.0f
```

And now, the same with the multiplication:

```
input1Data = input1Data * gain * (1.0f / 65535.0f); // gain, of course, will be
                                                    // automatically cast to float
                                                    // therefore the resulted factor 
                                                    // will have value from 0 to 1, 
                                                    // so input1Data too!
```

And I think this should compile too:

```
input1Data *= gain * (1.0f / 65535.0f);
```

optimizing first version a bit by not creating temporary data.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I made changes to the original code. If the CV_32F is replaced by CV_32S, can the input1Data still hold the resulting 32 bit data? Because, I am not looking for floating point image. I need 32 bit unsigned image(as gain and input data are ushort, 16 bit unsigned), but as per my research, it is not possible to get 32 bit unsigned image. This is troubling me a lot. After the gain multiplication, I still need to bring the 32 bit image back to 16 bit unsigned image(ushort). Please help. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: You could compute all the stuff in 32 bit float format and convert back to 16 bit int in the end before saving/displaying if speed performance doesnt matter.