# Averaging of two images with mask

Tags: c++, image, opencv, mask

I have two image like this:

[image: left image]
[image: right image]

I create two mask, which show me position of each image on scene.

[image: left mask]
[image: right mask]

I create mask which show me intersection of two images.

[image: bitwise and mask]

I create intersection mask with 
`cv::bitwise_and(mask_left, mask_right, mask_intersection);`

I want adding two images together. Where pixels of `mask_intersection` is white, I want use average value of pixels on both images. Here is result, where I just add one image on another. The problem is sharp border, which I want to solve with averaging of both images only on `mask_intersection`.

[image: panorama]

I don't know how to solve this problem the easiest way.

Comment: have a look at my answers in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22315904/blending-does-not-remove-seams-in-opencv/22324790#22324790 using linear crossblending

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For averaging the two images  where the mask intersect, you could use [`copyTo`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=clone#mat-copyto).

Supposing you have `maskIntersection`, `image1`, `image2` and `finalImage`, the code would look something like:

```
((image1 + image2) * 0.5).copyTo(finalImage, maskIntersection)
```

Even though this answers your question of averaging the two images, I don't think it will provide very good results. Blending two images together is usually a more involved process. Take a look at [this class](https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs231m/lectures/lecture-5-stitching-blending.pdf) to have a quick overview of what is required.

Comment: I see this not give very good results, but thank you for answer on my question and link for what is required.

Comment: We cannot just add because of overflow. Here is [link](http://answers.opencv.org/question/42911/solved-how-to-average-n-matrices-into-1/?answer=42917#post-id-42917) how accumulate this two images. Other code is work :)

Comment: you should convert the mats to avoid overflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26591889/how-to-convert-16-bit-image-to-32-bit-image-in-opencv

Answer (score 0):

Te process you are loocking for is called [blending](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/core/adding_images/adding_images.html), and you can achieve it using `cv::addWeighted()`, then just multiply the result by the mask to cut off zones of the image that you don´t want to blend.